# ¿Cómo puedo desplegar el valor de otro atributo diferente a llave externa en view.ctp?

Tags: php, cakephp

Tengo un programa en el cual tengo dos tablas: Assets y Types. En Assets existe una llave foránea a Types, cuya llave primaria es type_id. Yo quiero que siempre me aparezca el atributo "name" de Types en lugar de "type_id". Es por eso que utilizo el siguiente código en TypesTable.php:

```
$this->setDisplayField('name');
```

El cual funciona correctamente para los formularios de agregar y editar. El problema es que para consultar y el index me muestra solamente el type_id y he buscado en muchas páginas cómo hacer para cambiar esto pero lo único que encuentro es para los formularios de agregar y editar con el código escrito anteriormente. ¿Cómo podría hacer para que me despliegue el atributo "name" en lugar de "type_id" en consultar y el índice?

P.D: En el caso de consultar lo tengo formateado como una tabla (interfaz por defecto de bake) y no como un formulario con los campos bloqueados. De esta forma estoy desplegando el valor actualmente:

```
 <tr>
        <th scope="row"><?= __('Tipo') ?></th>
        <td><?= h($asset->type_id) ?></td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero tienes que definir la relación, en caso de que no lo hayas hecho o `bake` no lo haya hecho por ti

```
$this->belongsTo('Types', [
    'foreignKey' => 'type_id',
    'joinType' => 'INNER'
]);
```

Y en tu controlador lo llamas con `contain`:

```
$assets = $this->Assets->find()->contain(['Types']);
```

Si estás usando `paginate` lo declaras en `$this->paginate`

```
$this->paginate = [
    'contain' => ['Types']
];
```

Y en tu vista lo despliegas de esta manera:

```
<?= $asset->type->name ?>
```

Comment: ¡Funcionó perfecto! Muchas gracias.